# Reading spcific columns out of file

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7, numpy

I am having a problem reading big (300008 lines) output file of simulation code. I am using this function to read two columns of the file

```
def read2(filename,i1,i2):      
    "Read 2 ARRAYS from the i1-th and i2-th columns of a text file"  
    from numpy import *    # import numpy package    
    f = open(filename,'r')   # open the file      
    n = len(f.readlines())   # get number of rows    
    L1= [] ; L2=[]           # create empty lists                                
    f.seek(0)                # go to beginning of file     
    for k in range(n):         
        s = f.readline()     # read current row in string format         
        e =  s.split()        # split the elements of the string between white spaces   
        if "#" not in e[0]:         
           L1.append( e[i1-1] )         
           L2.append( e[i2-1] )     
    f.close()                # close input file     
    A1 = convert(L1,i1)     
    A2 = convert(L2,i2)     
    return A1,A2             # return arrays A1 & A2 to __main__ .
```

The problem is; it always giving me IndexError: list index out of range.

PS. convert is another function converting the string lists into arrays.

Comment: where is the error exactly taking place? on which line of the code.

Comment: Ouch you are reading the file twice just to get the number of lines. Suboptimal!

Comment: `np.genfromtxt` lets you specify which columns to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `len(f.readlines())`, the it comes to the end of the file, so `f.readline()` starts from the end of file every time. You get empty string all the time.

Comment: Doesn't the `seek(0)` get around that problem?  In any case the first `readlines` isn't necessary.